# How do I get my laptop to use its external monitor with Debian Wheezy?

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, debian-wheezy

with Debian Wheezy installed my laptop screen works fine but it doesn't seem to notice when an external monitor is plugged in.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15 (3537)

I think this is the device in question:

```
$ lspci -nn

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
```

but xrandr only reports one screen, even with a monitor plugged into the HDmI port.

```
$ xrandr

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1368 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768
default connected 1368x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768        0.0  
   1368x768        0.0*
```

Needless to say, this all works fine under Ubuntu, but I'd rather use Debian if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, but Debian Jessie seems to work perfectly with all the hardware on a Dell Inspiron 15 / 3537. Upgrade.